# finding id of nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to RoR so this may be very fundamental.  My structure keeps getting a level deeper and I can't figure out how to find the id anymore.

First you have a Company which can have many Users.  Users sign in and are authenticated and the current_user is saved in a cookie with the Session.

Since the User has one Company I can always find the Company.id through the current_user.

Next a Company has many Farms.  In farms create I can get the company id from the user cookie and the farm id is new so that works, and in farm show Rails knows which farm it is supposed to show.  So that level works.

Now I want to add that a Farm has many Blocks.  I am adding Blocks through the associated Farm show page, but the Blocks_controller doesn't know what farm page it is on (as far as I can tell, if it can any info is appreciated).

Here is the FarmsController create that works:

```
  def create
    company_id = current_user.company_id
    @company = Company.find(company_id)
    @farm = @company.farms.build(params[:farm])
    if @farm.save
      flash[:success] = "farm created"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
```

And this code just complains that it doesn't know what id I am talking about:

BlocksController

```
def create
    @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
    @block = @farm.blocks.build(params[:block])
end
```

This is displaying on the associated Farm show page, so if there is a way to capture the id I would love to know what it is.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three easiest ways to get that id is to:

1. Pass in that `farm_id` using a hidden form field. When creating the link to your blocks/new form just pass in the `farm_id` ie use a path like `new_blocks_path(:id => @farm.id)` inside your blocks controller you will want to make sure that the `farm_id` is set on the `Block` model.

   ```
   def new
     @block = new Block
     @block.farm_id = params[:farm_id]
   end
   ```

   Then if you are using form for the `farm_id` field (which should probably be of type hidden), it should contain the right id. Now change the first line in the "create" block method to

   ```
   @farm = Farm.find(params[:block][:farm_id])
   ```
2. You can combine the process of adding the blocks and the farms using nested forms. Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 for how to do this.
3. You can use nested RESTful resources to make sure that within the blocks controller you always have access to the farm id. For more information about how to do this try take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: Thank you, passing the id from the form in the hidden field was the big piece I was missing.

Comment: Good to hear. If it answers your question feel free to mark it as so :)